# How to retain listview items even when back pressed in android fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My doubt is i need to retain listview items even when back pressed in my fragment let me explain my full prob am having fragment name frag "a" attached to activity inside that fragment  there is another fragment called frag "b" . need to populate listview in fragment a from fragment b data dynamically dynamically i can populate listview in frag a but when i pressed back from frag a all the list items missing don't know what to do here is my code:

Fragment B(From_frag):

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 20-11-2015.
 */
public class NewContacts extends Fragment {
    EditText first_name,jobtitle,bussiness_phone,email,mobile,address_one,postal_code;
    Spinner gender_spinner,method_of_contact,state,city1;
    ContactView contactView=new ContactView();
    ContactSpinnerItem contactSpinnerItem;
ArrayList<ContactView>contactViews;
    Button save;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_contacts, container, false);
        first_name=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        jobtitle=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.jobtitle);
        bussiness_phone=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.businsphn);
        email=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.email_contact);
        mobile=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobnum);
        address_one=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addrss1_contact);
        postal_code=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postal_contact);
        //spinners
        gender_spinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        method_of_contact=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cntct_contact);
        state=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.state_contact);
        city1=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.city_contact);
        save =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btncontactsave);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contact_textbox();
                contact_spinner();
                Contactss contactss;
                contactss=(Contactss)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("contact");
         //   contactViews=new ArrayList<ContactView>();

             contactss.updatelist(contactView);
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }



    public void contact_textbox(){
        contactView.setFirst_name(first_name.getText().toString());
        contactView.setJob_title(jobtitle.getText().toString());
        contactView.setBusiness_phone(bussiness_phone.getText().toString());
        contactView.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
        contactView.setMobile(mobile.getText().toString());
        contactView.setAddrs_1(address_one.getText().toString());
        contactView.setPostal_code(postal_code.getText().toString());
    }
    public void contact_spinner(){
        List<ContactSpinnerItem>gender=new ArrayList<ContactSpinnerItem>();
        gender.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Male",1));
        gender.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Female",2));
        List<ContactSpinnerItem>methodofcontact=new ArrayList<ContactSpinnerItem>();
        methodofcontact.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Fax",1));
        methodofcontact.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Phone",2));
        methodofcontact.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Email",3));
        methodofcontact.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Other",4));
        List<ContactSpinnerItem>state_spinner=new ArrayList<ContactSpinnerItem>();
        state_spinner.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("TamilNadu",1));
        state_spinner.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Maharashtry",2));
        state_spinner.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Karnataka",3));
        List<ContactSpinnerItem>city=new ArrayList<ContactSpinnerItem>();
        city.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Chennai",1));
        city.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Banglore",2));
        city.add(new ContactSpinnerItem("Mumbai", 3));
//adapter for spinner

        ContactSpinnerAdapter genderadapter=new ContactSpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.spinnerlayout,gender);
        gender_spinner.setAdapter(genderadapter);
        ContactSpinnerAdapter method=new ContactSpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.spinnerlayout,methodofcontact);
        method_of_contact.setAdapter(method);
        ContactSpinnerAdapter state1=new ContactSpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.spinnerlayout,state_spinner);
        state.setAdapter(state1);
        ContactSpinnerAdapter citys=new ContactSpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.spinnerlayout,city);
        city1.setAdapter(citys);
        contactSpinnerItem=(ContactSpinnerItem)gender_spinner.getSelectedItem();
        contactView.setGender(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_text());
        contactView.setGender_id(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_value());
        //method of contanct
        contactSpinnerItem=(ContactSpinnerItem)method_of_contact.getSelectedItem();
        contactView.setMethod_of_contact(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_text());
        contactView.setMethod_id(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_value());
       //state
        contactSpinnerItem=(ContactSpinnerItem)state.getSelectedItem();
        contactView.setState_conatct(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_text());
        contactView.setState_id(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_value());
        //city
        contactSpinnerItem=(ContactSpinnerItem)city1.getSelectedItem();
        contactView.setCity(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_text());
        contactView.setCity_id(contactSpinnerItem.getContact_value());

    }

}
```

Here is my fragment a(To_fragment):

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 23-11-2015.
 */
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 08-10-2015.
 */
public class Contactss extends android.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Contactss(){}
    public ListView lv;
    Contactss contactss;
    public ContactListAdapter contactListAdapter;
    List<ContactView> newContactViews;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvcontacts);
        //ArrayList<NewsItem> listContact = GetlistContact();

            newContactViews = new ArrayList<ContactView>();
            contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.lvcontacts, newContactViews);
//contactss= (Contactss) getFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"contact");
            lv.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);


        return rootView;  }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"contact",contactss);

    }

    public void updatelist(ContactView obj) {

        newContactViews.add(obj);
        contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Fragment fragment=null;
        Button add = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment newfragmnet=new NewContacts();
        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.content_frame,newfragmnet);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }


}
```

how to retain list items even when back pressed confused with is can anyone help me out!

Comment: create a method in fragment and call this method in Activity.

Comment: can you share how to do that as am new for android